# Prove that the convex hull of a set is the smallest convex set containing that set

Tags: general-topology, convex-analysis, convex-hulls

How do you prove that the convex hull of **A** is the smallest convex set containing **A**?

edit: definition of a convex hull: Given a set **A** ⊆ ℝ<sup>n</sup> the set of all convex combinations of points from **A** is called the *convex hull* of **A**.

Comment: That depends: how do you *define* the convex hull of $A$?

Comment: What is your definition of the convex hull? And don’t you mean the smallest *convex* set containing **A**?

Comment: [This](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/69497/convex-hull-as-an-infinite-intersection) is related.

Answer (score 3):

Young, when you wrote

> How do you prove that the convex hull of A is the smallest set
>   containing A?

You meant that convex hull of A is the minimal convex set containing A, right?

To show this, which part is your definition?
The linear-algebraic characterization?

You can see that any intersection of convex sets containing A is also a convex set containing A.

Comment: Yea, the convex hull of A is the minimal convex set containing A. I guess what I need to prove is that the convex hull of A is itself a convex set containing A. How do I prove that or is it just by definition of a convex hull?

Comment: @Young: Let $\mathscr{C}$ be the collection of all convex sets containing $A$, and let $K=\bigcap\limits_{C\in\mathscr{C}}C$; certainly $K\supseteq A$, and you need to show that $K$ is convex. Let $x,y\in K$ and $t\in[0,1]$; you need to show that $tx+(1-t)y\in K$. Use the facts that (1) $x,y\in C$ for every $C\in\mathscr{C}$ and (2) every $C\in\mathscr{C}$ is convex.